# Horizontal Image Gallery

Tags: android, imageview, image-gallery

I am trying to implement a horizontal scrollable image gallery like on the one the Beatport app (See the screenshot just below the actionbar.)

[image: Beatport app screenshot]

Is there a library i can use to replicate the same effect?

Comment: Horizontal Scroll View? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html    https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/HorizontalGridView.html

Comment: If i use that the recyclerview or the horizonatal scrollview, how will i make the center image large and take up more screen estate than the other two images?

Comment: Try to find 'cover flow' library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use a [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with *Horizontal* [`LinearLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html).

eg:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**Update:**

If you want the centered image to be larger than two adjacent, you can use:

- Scale animation, to zoom in/out the images
- ***OR*** switch to a 3rd-party library like [Coverflow](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow) or [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) (no longer maintained).

Comment: And how do i get to make the center image larger that the two adjacent ones?

Comment: use viewpager with pager transformer to achieve whats within the pic